# Understanding a proof on Linear independence between squareroot of relatively primes

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, prime-numbers

I am trying to understand the following proof on "linear independence between relatively prime integers" http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51638.html.

I do not understand why proving the dimension is $2^s$ for a set of $s$ elements shows linear independence. In addition, I do not understand how we showed the dimension is exactly $2^s$ and why the dimension is $2^s$ for only $s$ elements? (it shows that it cannot be bigger than $2^s$, but not less than $2^s$.)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a field $K$ extending $\mathbb{Q}$, which you regard as a vector space of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
So every element of $K$ is of the form $q_1 + q_2 \alpha_2 + \ldots + q_n \alpha_n$.
Say $\beta$ is an irrational square root we want to add to $K$.
Since $\beta^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, you can easily check that $K(\beta) = \{k_1 + k_2 \beta : k_1, k_2\in K\}$ is the field generated by $K$ and $\beta$.
On one hand, $K(\beta)$ has degree at most $2n$, because it is spanned by $S = \{1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n, \beta, \alpha_2\beta, \ldots, \alpha_n \beta\}$.
On the other hand, if $S$ fails to be a basis, then you find $k_1 + k_2 \beta = 0$ for some $k_1, k_2 \in K$. Then $\beta = -\frac{k_1}{k_2}$ is in $K$.